# How to get the Title of a dynamic page during form submission in Wix Database

Tags: velo

I have made dynamic pages for my recipes in Wix and I had an user form for feedback in the dynamic pages , I'm able to get the feedback but can't able to know for which item they are ?

I want to get the title of recipe along with the user feedback into 
my database.

Please help me solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get information from the Dynamic Dataset like this:

```
var myVariable;

$w("#dynamicDataset").onReady( () => {
   let itemObj = $w("#dynamicDataset").getCurrentItem();
   myVariable = itemObj.fieldKey; //get the relevant field key
});
```

After this you can submit the data using the Wix Data API. Just make sure to pass on the **myVariable** so that you know where the submission came from. Sample code below.

```
let data = {
   fieldKey1: randomVariable,
   fieldKey2: someVariable,
   pageInfo: myVariable
}
wixData.insert('collectionName', data);
```

Read more about dynamic dataset's getCurrentItem() function here: https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-dataset.DynamicDataset.html#getCurrentItem

Also, the submission has to go through using the Wix Data API's insert() function. Read about it here: https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-data.html#insert

Comment: thnaks @Shan for the replay but i'm able tp get the title but cant able to push the title into the collection and its showing the following errors in the preview mode please help me solve it.

`data is :[object Object]
The result of the current item:[object Object]
The title is:Evade Subramanyam
Unhandled promise rejection Error: WDE0025: The testimonals2 collection does not exist. You cannot work with a collection using the Data API before it is created in the Editor.`

Comment: The error you get means that the collection 'testimonals2' does not exist. Check the database collection name.

Comment: I even tried with Changing into the collection name it didn't worked showing me the same error